# Can't Open .xip Xcode File

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-mojave

I'm trying to install XCode 10.2 (most recent) through the developer.apple.com download. After downloading the .xip file, I try to open it like many other people have suggested, but it just creates a XCode_10.2.xip.cpgz file. I click on that and it creates an XCode_10. 2 2.xip and the cycle continues.

Because of billing issues, I can't use the app store to download XCode.

Comment: What is your computer and what system are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You can install upgrades from the terminal without going to app store. If your running Mojave then Xcode 10.2 will run on your machine. If not, then Xcode 10.1 is latest version.

Go to the terminal and type  `sudo softwareupdate -i -a` and press Enter. This will download all application upgrades for your computer; not just Xcode.

Again, don't attempt to upgrade XCode unless you are running Mojave 10.14

Comment: Re: "Again, don't attempt to upgrade XCode unless you are running Mojave 10.14", why?

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution solved my problem. (P.S. I am running MacOSX Mojave 10.4)

Comment: would you mind accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side of my answer?  Glad this worked for you.